Getting loader image instead of chart and doesn't contain complete data
I have successfully embedded my Apache Superset dashboard within a React application and it is running smoothly. However, when attempting to download the report as a PDF, the downloaded file does not contain complete charts or data. Instead of the chart, I am getting a loading image.
I am using the Apache superset & hosted in AWS EC2.
Please refer to the attached screenshot for your reference.

Thanks in advance.

I have finally found a solution to my issue.
DASHBOARD_VIRTUALIZATION feature flag. is set to False.

